# Положение рюкзака относительно стула

Tags: грамотная-речь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рюкзак на стуле может стоять, лежать, сидеть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для рюкзака (относительно стула) могут быть использованы следующие глаголы: стоит (как на фотографии; в вертикальном положении), лежит (на боку, не вертикально), располагается, размещается, находится, валяется, висит (на спинке).
Ещё его можно прислонить к столу или к спинке стула.

Ни одно из [значений глагола "сидеть"](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/4855) нашему стулу не подходит. Так что говорить "рюкзак сидит на стуле" нельзя.

*Он потер глаза и огляделся вокруг – на стуле стоял ее рюкзак...* (А. Тарасов)
*Рюкзак так и остался лежать на стуле за столиком, где мы сидели* (Д. Томчук).
*Пустой рюкзак валялся на стуле...* (Д. Макмахон)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а где вы находите примеры употребления сочетаний в литературе?

Comment: Гугл нам с Вами в помощь. Набираю _рюкзак стоял на стуле_ и выбираю из найденных предложений те, которые "заслуживают доверия": из книг, из статей, из словарей и учебных пособий... Иногда конкретно указываю автора. Можно обратиться и к НКРЯ.

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос по фото, то на фото рюкзак стоит на стуле. 
Лежит - это если вы определяете где у рюкзака спинка либо 'живот' и располагаете на сидении соответственно лежачему положению. 
Сидит - для рюкзака невозможное, но если под "сидит" имеется в виду "стоит" либо "лежит", то почему бы и "нет"?

Если вопрос не по приведённому фото, то рюкзак может ещё висеть на стуле.

Comment: "...если под "сидит" имеется в виду "стоит" либо "лежит", то почему бы и "нет?" Это как понять?

Comment: Просто, слово "сидит" используется в смысле "стоит" либо "лежит". В переносном смысле.

Comment: В каком словаре это зафиксировано?

Comment: Не понял? В каком словаре зафиксировано что? Разное имение в виду? На это словари не могут дать ответ, ведь человек может заложить свой собственный переносной смысл любому слову. Поймите разницу: "называть понятия своими именами" и "называть понятия их именами". Первое - смысл; второе - толк.

Comment: Переносное значение возникает тогда, когда между между предметами, понятиями есть общность. Между этими двумя понятиями нет никакой общности. Следовательно, слово сидит не употребляется в значении стоит или лежит.

Comment: Если у слова возникает переносное значение, оно фиксируется словарями.

Comment: Где вы видели изменяемые словари Даля, Ефремовой, Ожегова?

Comment: Вы сами понимаете, о чем говорите?

Comment: Ещё раз: "называть вещи своими именами" и "называть вещи их именами" - над этими выражениями подумайте, потому что они четко показывают использование слов по усмотрению человека.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90836/discussion-between--and-).